# Trying to overwrite media="print" stylesheet in Drupal 6

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to overwrite the default media="print" stylesheet that is defined in my site's Drupal build. However, I cannot find where the stylesheet is. It seems as if Drupal builds these stylesheets and places them in a folder, but I need to know where these styles are coming from so that I can overwrite them.

Here is a link to my site: https://www.redhatsociety.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resides in misc/print.css or any core enabled theme (in themes/). Or if your theme is a sub theme it could be your base theme in sites/all/themes.
See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/misc!print.css/6
In your .info file in your theme folder you can add your own print css file.

```
stylesheets[print][] = css/print.css
```

Comment: Adding my own to that .info file worked perfectly. Thank you so much!